# Why is there a public burn function in this Fantom Smart contract?

Tags: solidity, remix, ether, fantom

I was reviewing some of the smart contracts on Fantom and came across this function in ZOO:

https://github.com/ZooEcosystem/ZooCoin/blob/main/contracts/ZOO.sol

Whilst they have an internal burn function which I assume can only be used by the contract creators but there is also use of a public burn function? Does this mean in this Smart contract users are can just burn their own coins or others?

The public Burn function:

```
abstract contract ERC20Burnable is Context, ERC20 {
    /**
     * @dev Destroys `amount` tokens from the caller.
     *
     * See {ERC20-_burn}.
     */
    function burn(uint256 amount) public virtual {
        _burn(_msgSender(), amount);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Destroys `amount` tokens from `account`, deducting from the caller's
     * allowance.
     *
     * See {ERC20-_burn} and {ERC20-allowance}.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - the caller must have allowance for ``accounts``'s tokens of at least
     * `amount`.
     */
    function burnFrom(address account, uint256 amount) public virtual {
        uint256 currentAllowance = allowance(account, _msgSender());
        require(currentAllowance >= amount, "ERC20: burn amount exceeds allowance");
        _approve(account, _msgSender(), currentAllowance - amount);
        _burn(account, amount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first burn function is the internal `_burn` function which is belong to Openzeppelin's ERC20 token. Since this function is internal, it should be called from contracts own function `burn`. What public `burn` function does is it simply calls the internal `_burn` function.

And for the `burnFrom` function, it is simply a more secure way to do `burn`.

So yes, users burn their own tokens.
And no, users cant burn others tokens.

Comment: Oh I see, so even if the public burn or burnFrom functions are called they still need access to the internal functions of the contract. so they'll just fail if used externally?

Something I don't quite understand though, why would these functions ever need to be public?